# Find shortest prefix in a string in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I am new to C and would appreciate your help in a code.
I need to allocate dynamically an array and check which prefix in the string is the shortest that it's concatenation builds the string, and print it and it's length.

Here are a few examples for the outputs:

1. for "ababab", the output should be: "ab" of length 2
2. for "aaaa", the output should be: "a" of length 1
3. for "abcaabca", the output should be: "abca" of length 4
4. for "abcdefg", the output should be: "abcdefg" of length 7
5. for "acacaac" the output should be "acacaac" of length 7

My problem is that I don't know how to build the function that supposed to to it. The cases in which the string contains only the same letter, or all letters are different from each other are fine, but I don't know how to take care of all the other cases.

I can't use another string for this code, but I'm allowed to use other pointers 
to help me.

Thanks

Comment: You really need to start writing some code.  Your question, as posted, is overly broad and effectively asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: this site is not for homeworks.

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the effective code, but the idea itself.

First, this "prefix" of yours has a length that is a divisor of the big length. So if the length i of the prefix doesn't divide the length n of the string then it should be skipped.

To check if a length i is valid, then you need to compare the characters from positions j and j+i, for all possible values of j.

Answer (score 1):

It can be pretty simple, two nested loops, the outer one being a for, from 1 to length/2, and the inner a while, using a pointer increased in each step by the value of the iteration variable of the outer loop. Inside the loop you can use strncmp() to compare the a proper substring, and break the loop if comparison fails. If all comparisons are OK, you have found the "shortest prefix", so you can break the (for) loop. The for loop can be optimized too, by skipping the lengths that are not divisors of the input string length.

This doesn't require making a copy or copies.

And yes, I will leave you actually write the code.

Answer (score 0):

You said you cannot use another string, hopefully You are allowed to use a small temporary array of booleans to count the number of different characters in the string.

1- Find the number of different characters in the string, using an array of boolean. Let this number be x.

2- check if the first x characters constitute a prefix. (check each pointer position p against p+x, p+2x, etc). If unsuccessful, the shortest prefix is the whole string.

In between, you can make it faster by quickly checking if x *divides* the length of the string..